# making a sequence of numbers in octave and matlab

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab, octave

I know I can make a sequence of numbers in matlab / octave
using `x=1:1:5`  and it will give me `1,2,3,4,5` but how can I get a sequence to be

```
1,1/2,1/4,1/6,1/8,1/10...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
1./[1,2.*(1:1:5)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
1./[1,(2:2:20)]
```

......................

Comment: Good syntax, but not the sequence the OP asked about.

Comment: @horchler fixed